# pd.merge Return Larger Volume of Rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I got to data frame with the same string columns that I want to merge together.

```
df.shape

(367923, 3)

df1.shape

(308185, 3)

df = pd.merge(df, df1, how='outer')
```

*MemoryError: Unable to allocate 513. GiB for an array with shape (68897953636,) and data type int64*

How come the size of the merged data frame become 68897953636? I expected ‭616,370‬. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: try `pd.concat([df,df1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what happened from the information you've provided, but if you have the same columns in both dataframes and just want to add all the rows in the same dataframe, pd.concat is probably the function you're looking for.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

And then get rid of any duplicates with df.drop_duplicates if you need to.

As for why you got the result you did, my guess is that since you didn't provide which columns to merge on with pd.merge, pandas gave you all possible combinations of the two dataframes combined.